# NSSortDescriptor issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am making a contact book App where I am fetching names from AddressBook and stored them in Core data and displayed the names on a table using `NSFetchedResultsController.However` the first index and section that comes up is # followed by the alphabets. But I want to do it like it is in native contact app i.e. # index should come at last.
I used the following `NSortDescriptor`:

> sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"fullName" ascending:YES ];

here "fullName" is the `key` in core data which is made by concatenating first name and last name.
And the section identifier is the first letter of "fullName" if the `fullName` doesn't start with alphabet, its section identifier is #.
I had searched about it and used `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch` in the `NSortDescriptor` comparator but it didn't worked. If any one has any idea then let me know.

Here goes my code:

```
NSString *special = @"\uE000";
if ([[self sectionName:contactName] isEqualToString:@"#"]) {                           
    sortName = [special stringByAppendingString:contactName];
}
else{
    sortName = contactName;
}
[newContact setValue:[self sectionIdentifier:sortName] forKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
[newContact setValue:sortName forKey:@"sortName"];
```

And here is the sort descriptor:

```
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sortName" ascending:YES];
```

`[self sectionIdentifier:sortName]` this method returns # if sortName starts with a non alphabet and else it returns the alphabet by which it starts.

newContact is the object of the entity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could store an additional attribute `sortName` in the entity, which is `fullName` if the name starts with a letter, and `<C>fullName` otherwise. `<C>` is a fixed character which is "greater" than all letters. For example

```
NSString *special = @"\uE000";
if ("fullName starts with letter")
    sortName = fullName;
else
    sortName = [special stringByAppendingString:fullName];
```

Now you can sort according to `sortName`, and the section identifier would be "#" if `sortName` starts with the special character.

The disadvantage is that you have to store an additional attribute, the advantage is that you can continue to use a fetched results controller (which can use only persistent attributes for sorting).

**UPDATE:** It can actually be done a bit easier.

When you create a new entry, you set `sectionIdentifier` to the first character of the name if it is a letter, and to the special character otherwise:

```
NSString *special = @"\uE000";

if ([[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[contact.contactName characterAtIndex:0]]) {
    contact.sectionIdentifier = [contact.contactName substringToIndex:1];
} else {
    contact.sectionIdentifier = special;
}
```

The fetched results controller uses `sectionIdentifier` for grouping and sorting the sections. Entries within each section are sorted by `contactName`:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Contact"];
NSSortDescriptor *sort1 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sectionIdentifier"
             ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"contactName"
             ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sort1, sort2]];
self.frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                   managedObjectContext:self.context
                     sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier"
                              cacheName:nil];
```

All non-letter entries are now grouped in the last section. The final step is to display the correct section header `#` for the last section:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.frc sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    NSString *title = [sectionInfo name];
    if ([title isEqualToString:special])
        title = @"#";
    return title;
}
```

Comment: I tried your approach, but it doesn't return correct section name and  index

Comment: @user1632153: Can you put your code (or a reduced example project) somewhere where I can download it? I would try to figure out a solution.

Comment: @user1632153: Please see my updated answer. I have tested it myself and it seems to work, so I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: @Martin R My own testing has shown that the `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` method doesn't get called at all when the `NSFetchedResultsController` is initialized with a non-nil `sectionNameKeyPath`. Therefore the special character doesn't get replaced with the #.

Comment: @JohnTopley: I can not confirm that, it worked (with sectionNameKeyPath) in my test project. Perhaps you have a `viewForHeaderInSection` method that takes precedence?

Comment: @Martin R D'oh! I'd completely forgotten that I'd overridden that method! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You could split up the results into two arrays, one that starts with alpha characters, and one that doesn't. Then just add the two together. Assuming you are starting with an array of managed objects called `results`:

```
//Create the sort descriptor array
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"fullName" ascending:YES];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sd];

//Create a sorted array of objects where fullName starts with an alpha character
//using a Regex

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fullName MATCHES '^[a-zA-Z].*'"];

NSArray *alpha = [[results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

//Now use the alpha array to create an array of objects where the fullName does not
//start with an alpha character

NSMutableArray *nonAlpha = [results mutableCopy];

[nonAlpha removeObjectsInArray:alpha];

[nonAlpha sortUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

//Now put them back together again

NSArray *sortedResults = [alpha arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:nonAlpha];

//And if you're not using ARC!
[nonAlpha release];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"fullName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Just make sure it doesn't affect performance in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing your own comparator Function

Assuming that it is sorting ManagedObjects and they all have fullName as a field, then the following may help.

```
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"FullName" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [[obj1 objectForKey:@"fullName"] compare:[obj2 objectForKey:@"fullName"] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    }];
```

The advantage of this is you can also write the NSLog for each comparison and see what is happening.

Comment: Application crashes by using this

Comment: This comes in debugger:   unsupported NSSortDescriptor (comparator blocks are not supported)