# Core data sign sort descriptor

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I want to sort data by sign. In SQLite function "sign" works fine. But in Core Data I can't repeat this. I've tryed this:

```
    NSSortDescriptor* signSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"id" ascending:NO comparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSNumber* obj1, NSNumber* obj2) {
        int val1 = sign([obj1 integerValue]);
        int val2 = sign([obj2 integerValue]);
        return (val1 < val2) ? NSOrderedAscending : (val1 > val2) ? NSOrderedDescending : NSOrderedSame;
    }];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[signSortDescriptor];
```

Doesn't work on iOS 6.1(error: "unsupported NSSortDescriptor (comparator blocks are not supported)"), fine on iOS 5.1 (I think it sort after get array of result, but not sure)

Tryed this:

```
    NSSortDescriptor* signSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sign(id)" ascending:NO];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[signSortDescriptor];
```

But get error...

Comment: How you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800062/nssortdescriptor-issue

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a special comparison by sign.
If the `id` is a `NSNumber`, just sort the values by `id`. They will be also sorted by sign and I don't think there will be a performance impact.

Comment: I have complex sort descriptor. First sort by sign id decreasing, second- absolute ascending. Ex: 3 4 7 0 -2 -5 -10. I can simple solve my problem, but I want to know how to do sign sort in db.

Comment: @Sk0prion: You cannot use a Objective-C based sort descriptor for a Core Data fetch request. Only persistent attributes and certain comparator function are allowed (see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW11). If you need a special sort order, you will have to add another attribute that implies this order - or sort in memory after fetching the objects.