# How can I change section ordering with NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I'm setting up an NSFetchRequest with the following sort descriptor:

```
[sortDescriptors addObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"color" ascending:YES]];
```

I'm setting the sectionNameKeyPath for the NSFetchedResultsController to be the "color" attribute.

The results are sorted into sections based on color, as I would expect.

It's valid for the "color" attribute to be an empty string "" for some objects. Those are all grouped together in the first section, since they sort before all other names. However, I'd like them to appear as the final section, not the first section, without affecting the search order of the remaining objects.

For example, currently the sections might be:

```
 ""
 "green"
 "red"
 "yellow"
```

But I'd like the sections to be in the order:

```
 "green"
 "red"
 "yellow"
 ""
```

Is there some way to write the sort descriptor to get this behavior? I've been unable to come up with anything myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sort descriptor for a (SQLite based) Core Data fetch request can only use some standard comparator methods and only use (persistent) attributes stored in the database. To get
a non-standard order you will have to add an additional attribute to the entity and
use that for sorting.

Comment: and that additional attribute could be a BOOL "hasValidColor", which is changed in the overwritten setter that sets the color attribute. You would then sort by "hasValidColor" and "color".

Comment: @MatthiasBauch: I am not sure if you can use *two* sort descriptors for the `sectionNameKeyPath`. The documentation says that `sectionNameKeyPath` must generate the same ordering as the *first* sort descriptor. Therefore I thought of an attribute "xcolor" that is some "large string" if "color" is empty, and equal to "color" otherwise.

Comment: You are of course correct. I totally forgot about the sectioning.

Comment: Some additional thoughts.

Comment: 1. Is it possible to have two levels of sorting on the same attribute? Something like:

    <sort on color ascending>.
        <sort on color != "">

This would require stable sorting, which I'm not sure is guaranteed by Core Data. And it would require being able to write a predicate for color != "", which I haven't been able to figure out.

Comment: 2. Another thought I had was to leave the fetched results as is. Then, inside of the objectAtIndexPath, titleForSection, and related functions I can return results for (section + 1) % numberOfSections. Internally, nothing has changed. But to the caller, this would make the first section appear to be last. This could be tricky to get correct. And tricky is almost always problematic.

Comment: 3. I could copy the fetched results into an NSArray, moving the first section to be last. This is perhaps the most flexible option, since I could move any sections around as I see fit. But elegant, it is not.

Comment: @user2592842: 1) You can have multiple levels of sorting, but *not* for the section key (see my reply to Matthias above). - 2) I think that should be possible, but very tricky. Both the table view data source methods and the FRC delegate methods would have to map between "table view section" and "FRC section". - 3) That is of course possible. The only disadvantage is that the table is no longer updated automatically when objects are inserted/deleted/changed. - Hope that helps!

Comment: I guess the answer is "not directly supported by Core Data--roll your own". Heh. Maybe I should just set the default initializer for the sort field to 0xff (or whatever its UTF-8 equivalent is) instead of "". Yuck. Anyway, thanks for the help. I now know better what some of the trade-offs are for the various options I've got. (Of course if you think of something else later on, let me know.)

Comment: On a related question, as far as #1 (above) goes, I wonder if Core Data really cares how many levels of sorting are done on the section key. As long as the table returned from the SQL query is in the correct order for grouping, I'd think Core Data wouldn't care how you got there. Just guessing, though.

Comment: @user2592842: I have used U+E000 in a similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12940825/1187415), because international character "ä, €, ø" can have Unicodes > 0xFF. - I never tried to use more than one sort descriptor for the section key. The documentation states *"the first sort descriptor in the array is used to group the objects into sections"*.

Comment: @user2592842: Please let me know if you need more information. Otherwise note that you can "accept" an answer that helped by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: After playing around for a bit, I decided to go with #2. Thanks for the help working through this.